Can I make Bitswapped Enum in Python Construct object?
I using Python Construct module for build\parse binary objects.
Is it possible to swap Enum somehow?
Because I have wrong order of my "Configuration" Enum, also, "Side" Enum works fine.
Byte_EOL = BitsSwapped(
    BitStruct(
        "1_Present" / Flag,     
        "2_Present" / Flag,
        "2_Strategy" / Flag,
        "Side" / Enum(              
            BitsInteger(1),                     
            Left_Side=0,
            Right_Side=1
        ),                    
        "3_Present" / Flag,             
        "3_Strategy" / Flag,        
        "Configuration" / Enum(      
            BitsInteger(2),
            No=0,
            Two=1,
            Right=2,
            Left=3
        )
    )
)

Try to parse byte 0x43 (0100 0011):
EOL: Container: 
    1_Present = True
    2_Present = True
    2_Strategy = False
    Side = (enum) Left_Side 0
    3_Present = False
    3_Strategy = False
    Configuration = (enum) Right 2        <= not correct, should be "(enum) Two 1"

But, unfortunately, seems like I have a bit swapped Enum :D

Well, yeah, you can bitswap a construct enum. You told the library to do that, and it did. It's not clear why you're asking this.

My question is about Enum inside my BitsSwapped object
I`ve tried that, like BitsSwapped(Enum()), and unfortunately, it show (enum) (unknown) 256 in my case :(

Looking at the docs, it looks like BitsSwapped operates on a byte-wise basis, so you can't use it to swap two specific bits within a byte. It looks like what you really want to reverse is the field order, not the bit order, so why not just take out BitsSwapped and declare your fields in the opposite order?

Yep. You right... So, only in my case - manually do "swapping bits", right?
